# a synonymous phrase for 'to increase tenfold'

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

I know that we can say the following in the context of math:

> We increase a number by a factor of ten.
>
> We increase a number tenfold

Remind me please of what else we can say in this context?

Can we say that

> we increase a number ten times, or
>
> a number was increased ten times, or
>
> a number became ten times more/ten times greater, or
>
> a number became ten times as much ?

Comment: multiply a number by 10

Comment: @ CarSmack thanks. What about my examples in which I use the word 'times'. Is it acceptable in English?  To be more precise, I want to mention the number multiplied by 't', where t is a number in a certain set.

Comment: You might also use "increase by 900%".

Comment: @  CopperKettle in no event! If I use "increase by", then there will be another meaning.

Comment: In your 2nd box, the first and second options don't necessarily imply a 10-fold increase. For instance, the value of the increase could have been 1 or some other number (like an iteration).

Comment: The phrase "order of magnitude" comes to mind, though it's a little more vague, and used more in comparisons.

Comment: In informal math talk, "times it with 10" is perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we say that

> we increase a number ten times

No, because you cannot assume that each "increase" is the original number.

> a number was increased ten times

for the same reason.

> a number became ten times more/ten times greater

maybe but far too many words.

> a number became ten times as much

OK. But for the last two examples, *became* is not a word generally used in the description of math equations.